# how to increment column value using update query

Tags: sql-server

I tried below query to update ID with unique values in table ELEM_DUP3 but all ID got updated with same value.

```
UPDATE DW.ELEM_DUP3
 FROM ( SELECT MAX(ID) AS ID
    FROM DW.ELEM ) S
 SET ID = (S.ID + 1)
```

```
Data in table:      After Update:
ID Name             ID Name
5 test8              8 test8
6 test9              8 test9
7 test10             8 test10
```

Expected result:

```
ID Name
8 test8
9 test9
10 test10
```

Could any one help where am I wrong?

Comment: please tag the dbms you are using like  SQLserver or oracle..

Comment: It's because you use this: SELECT MAX(ID), it will always give you 8 because max(id) in data table is 7.

Comment: There is no WHERE clause, so all rows will be updated with the same value.

Comment: add a where clause in the query to get the id of current row , then update

Comment: You have Select MAX(ID) as the ID you refer to in your outer query. It will return a constant value (of 8 in your case). That is why you get your issue.

Comment: `UPDATE ELEM_DUP3 SET ID=ID+1`

Comment: What database? sql server? Oracle? You want to update each line by a fixed amount: 3. Where does 3 come from? it is 7-5+1 right? To get 3 you run `SELECT MAX(ID) - MIN(ID) + 1 FROM Table`. Confirm that and confirm the platform please

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Hi all,I'm using SQLserver.

Answer (score 2):

```
 UPDATE DW.ELEM_DUP3 D
 FROM ( SELECT ID AS ID
 FROM DW.ELEM Where ID=D.ID) S
 SET D.ID = (S.ID + 1)
```

It should work for you

Answer (score 0):

Given the requirements, this does what you want:

```
UPDATE DW.ELEM_DUP3
SET ID = ID + (SELECT MAX(ID)-MIN(ID)+1 FROM DW.ELEM_DUP3)
```

You can run it repeatedly and it will keep incrementing the field